# How to move a line to the 2nd axis in Dash (by plot.ly)

Tags: linechart, plotly-dash

I'm creating a simple line chart in Dash (by plot.ly) with two time series.

I would like to shift one time series to the 2nd axis, but have been unable to get this to work. Below is my snippet of chart code. Any help is appreciated.

```
        "data": [
            dict(
                x=dff[timestamps],
                y=dff[inp_1],
                name=inp_1,
                marker=dict(color=colors[0]),
            ),
            dict(
                x=dff[timestamps],
                y=dff[inp_2],
                name=inp_2,
                marker=dict(color=colors[1]),
            ),
        ],
        "layout": dict(margin={"l": 40, "b": 20, "t": 25, "r": 10})
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution as below:

```
        "data": [
            dict(
                x=dff[timestamps],
                y=dff[inp_1],
                name=inp_1,
                marker=dict(color=colors[0]),
            ),
            dict(
                x=dff[timestamps],
                y=dff[inp_2],
                name=inp_2,
                marker=dict(color=colors[1]),
                yaxis="y2",
            ),
        ],
        "layout": dict(margin={"l": 40, "b": 20, "t": 25, "r": 10},yaxis2=dict(overlaying="y", side="right"))
```